# Term for wavelength-restricted or filtered light having a fairly pure color besides "colored light"?

Tags: synonyms, colors

I've just used "colored light" in the title to my History of Science and Mathematics SE question [Did Newton every use filtered or prism-dispersed colored light to view “Newton's rings” or other thin-film interference effects?](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/q/13311/3869) and I'm simply wondering if there available a different way to say it.

"Colored" is a valid and accurate term in this technical context but the word *also* has a substantial history when applied to people ([discussion](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/119166/217285)). I'm not saying it necessarily needs to be replaced in this particular case, I'm simply curious if an alternate exists.

**Question:** Is there a term for wavelength-restricted or filtered light having a fairly pure color besides "colored light"?

---

[Thesaurus.com; colored](https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/colored) provides terms that obviously won't work: dyed, flushed, glowing, hued, shaded, stained, tinged, tinted, washed

[Merriam-Webster thesaurus/colored](https://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/colored) returns: chromatic, colorful, kaleidoscopic, motley, multicolored, multihued, polychromatic, polychrome, prismatic, rainbow, varicolored, varied, variegated, various

and if the wavelength range were very narrow one can use *monochromatic* but usually we don't use monochromatic to things like wide-band filter (e.g. stained glass, gel filters).

I then turned to Lennon's lyrics to [Lucy in the Sky with Diamonds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucy_in_the_Sky_with_Diamonds) and there's "Cellophane flowers of yellow and green" and "With plasticine porters with looking glass ties" which invoke colorful images but offer no help here.

Comment: @WeatherVane yes there are challenges when terms are used one way in technical contexts and another in common usage. We can say something weighs 10 kg and people will know what you mean, but weight and mass are fundamentally immiscible. In optics or physics proper there is no exact definition for monochromatic, but most folks would call a laser monochromatic and many would include a *low pressure* mercury or sodium light. Fewer still would include a single color LED as a monochromatic light source. Almost none would call a "band" monochromatic.

Comment: If there is no exact definition, does that not make a succinct title with its meaning expanded at greater length (five words replaced by one)? It seems open for you to define what you are exploring.

Comment: @WeatherVane I don't understand what you are saying or asking. Are you suggesting an improvement to the wording of the post, or helping me explore possible answers, or something else?

Comment: I am not. I am asking *for a term* and have already explained that "...I'm simply wondering if there available a different way to say it... in this technical context" and "*I'm not saying it necessarily needs to be replaced in this particular case*, I'm simply curious if an alternate exists." I am sorry but I still find it difficult to understand what you are driving at. I'm convinced the question is clear and on-topic.

Comment: Look up [Broadening in laser systems; Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_broadening), which seems to imply that true monochromatism is a fiction, and that the only practical usage of 'monochromatic' is  (Dictionary.com, my bolding) 'Having or **appearing to have** only one color'. This is the everyday English usage, appropriate on ELU. For more precision, you'll have to use 'covering the narrow range of wavelengths λ1 - λ2'.

Comment: *narrow-band* is often used in wireless for a small range of frequencies. It may not fit exactly, but as others have said you'll struggle to find a better word. And if you're looking for a technical term, you should ask in a technical forum.

Comment: @StuartF narrow-band is good; that might be something that most people can at least get some idea from in conjunction with "filtered" as it speaks to what kind of filtering we're talking about. If the question opens up again please consider posting that as an answer, *thanks!*

Comment: @David There are some uses of 'colored' at least in AmE that are considered offensive (see the discussion link the OP gave). Other contexts are not at all offensive "rose-colored glasses".

Comment: @Mitch2 You should tell that to the National Association for the Advancement of Colored People. Who are they offending?

Answer (score 4):

*Monochromatic* really is likely to be the best word.

[Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/monochromatic) has *using only black, white, and grey, or using only one colour* as the primary definition, with *(Physics) (of light) having a single wavelength...* as secondary.

I work in optical physics so use the 2nd definition all the time definition) or "of a single colour".  It's never really true anyway, as linewidths never really reach zero, but for lasers and atomic lines is close enough.

The more general meaning does come into the optical field with thing like colour-separation filters (RGB or CMY filter sets for example).  Each clearly has a broad bandwidth, but translates to one class of pixel or one ink in reproduction.

The downside is that "monochromatic" all too often refers to greyscale or black-and-white.  But you mention gels, so here's an example of a [tutorial on stage lighting](https://www.learnstagelighting.com/how-do-i-use-color-effectively/) that refers to "monochromatic lighting schemes"

Comment: I note that in Synchrotrons used as a light source for experiments (for example) there are devices called "monochromators" which "transmit[s] a mechanically selectable narrow band of wavelengths of light or other radiation." Pretty strong evidence for the technical use of the term, and also speaks to the OP's concern that "Almost none would call a "band" monochromatic." Many years ago a friend of mine moved to Brasil to work with one of these particle accelerators in the study of Biology.

Comment: @Yorik I have a visible/near infra-red monochromator at work, and have used many before. As I said, I'm more familiar with this use. But the non-physics use is also valid, and my last link demonstrates that it's used just as the OP might like, for wide bands (I also have a selection of theatrical gels here, with their spectra, and most bands are indeed wide)

Answer (score 0):

The term is *coherent* light, or light that is *frequency coherent*.

Lasers do much of their magic because the light is generated in such a way that the light is made all at once and also of the same color. The waves are matched peak for peak and valley for valley. This can be done since all the waves are of the same frequency. The waves are *temporally coherent*, that is, matched peaks and valleys. They are also *spatially coherent*, that is, in frequency. I  lood forward to being corrected on one of these.

from https://www.wordnik.com/words/coherent%20light
coherent light
n.
Light in which the phases of all electromagnetic waves at each point on a line normal to the direction of the the beam are identical. Coherent light is usually monochromatic, and the most common source of such light for practical uses is from a laser.
n.
Light of a uniform wavelength and phase; as used in lasers

Also
http://amasci.com/miscon/coherenc.html

Comment: +1 but it's a bit of a sticky wicket: [Low-pressure sodium lamps only give monochromatic yellow light and so inhibit color vision at night.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sodium-vapor_lamp#Low-pressure_sodium) but not so many people would refer to this as *coherent light*. The problem is that coherence is not a binary property, it's a question of degree. But I don't want to belabor the point because this site is probably not for those types of discussions. *Thanks!*

Comment: If monochromatic is not appropriate, then coherent certainly isn't.

Comment: No. Monochromatic is the correct term.